# Wordpress Htaccess URL Rewriting with GET parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My website is on wordpress. I want to rewrite the url.
Like this was the url of my themes index page

http://localhost/wp/?id=test

I want it like this
http://localhost/wp/test

Where i can take this 'test' as GET parameter.

Comment: clean your .htaccess file and set permalink as a post type

Answer (score 0):

Please go to:

Wordpress *Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks*

and set "/%category%/%postname%/" as Custom Structure.

Comment: After doing this how i will get the get parameter value in my page? Because write now it was redirecting me to not found page

Comment: You need to have template file for this post type inside theme folder. And inside this file you can use $post object (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post) to get any data from this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux web hosting, go here /wp-admin/options-permalink.php and select 'post name'.

If you are using windows web hosting,

```html
If you are using linux web hosting, go here /wp-admin/options-permalink.php and select 'post name'.

If you are using windows web hosting, create a web.config file and paste below codes.

<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name=”wordpress” patternSyntax=”Wildcard”>
<match url=”*” />
<conditions>
<add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsFile” negate=”true” />
<add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsDirectory” negate=”true” />
</conditions>
<action type=”Rewrite” url=”index.php” />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```